# how to get img from selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

how to get the image hyperlink by using the selenium package.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://m.imdb.com/feature/bornondate")
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='poster ']")
li = [["Name","Movie Title","Image"]]
for i in  elements:
    print i.find_element_by_tag_name("img") ##I am not sure how to get the URL
    new_line= i.text.splitlines()
    #print new_line[0] , " " , new_line[1]
    li.append(new_line)

print li
```

Writing the data to CSV file

```
with open ('imdb.csv','wb')as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    a.writerows(li)
```

Comment: You shouldn't use XPath in this case: `//a[@class='poster ']`. In terms of HTML, this could just as well be `<a class="poster">`, `<a class=" poster">` or `<a class=" poster ">`. Better use a CSS selector: `a.poster`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To get a element property like src you need to call the get_attribute('attr_name') property.

You just need to add the following code to your for cycle:

```
for i in elements:
    image = i.find_element_by_tag_name("img")
    img_src = image.get_attribute("src")
```